# spark3.1.1 take too lone time to resove long sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a long sql with big wide table , when I use spark2.4 it take about 30-40 minutes to write data, when I use spark3.1.1 it will take about 60-80 minutes, event use more memory, then I set debug level to check with spark3.1, I find it take a long time to resove sql in analyze phase, I know the sql is complicated and have many fields, I have to set         sparkConf.set("spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations","1000");
is there a way to do the resolve phase in mutiple thread to do it quickly? thanks